# Loop through files and use functions, then use that result to form a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, file, bigdata

I have a directory of sorted bam files that I want to use `pileup` function to. The output of `pileup` function is a dataframe. Then I would like to use the result of each file and form a dataframe.

For each file, I use the follow codes:

```
r16<-pileup(filename, index=filename, scanBamParam = ScanBamParam(), pileupParam = PileupParam())
r16$sample_id <- "sample id"
```

For `sample_id` column, I would like it to be the name of the file, for example:

- the file name is `file1.sorted.bam`, I would like `sample_id` to be `file1`

And after all files are processed, I would use `rbind` to get a big dataframe and save it to a RData file.

So far, I have tried to use the loops on them, but it is not giving me any outputs.

```
library(pasillaBamSubset)
library(Rsamtools)
filenames<-Sys.glob("*.sorted.bam")
for (file in filenames) {
  output <- pileup(pileup(filenames, index=filenames, scanBamParam = ScanBamParam(), pileupParam = PileupParam()))
  save(output, file = "res.RData")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to stack all the data.frames on top of each other (row bind). `map` (from purrr) or `lapply` can apply a function to each item in
a given list/vector (each filename in this case). `map_dfr` does the same and row binds all the outputs.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "*.sorted.bam")

library(purrr)
purrr::map_dfr(filenames, ~pileup(.x, 
                                  index = .x,
                                  scanBamParam = ScanBamParam(),
                                  pileupParam = PileupParam()))
```